# After checked action

Tags: javascript, html, css

Link to my work: http://bwm350.jjwalkerdesign.com/toDo.html

I believe my code is too long to place into here, so here is the link to what I am referring to.

My issue is when I click the checkbox after clicking placing an item into the list, my red line does not go across the item and acts as if it is behind it.

Example: Type in Dog, then click the checkbox. The red line goes in between my two icons instead of over "Dog".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If the code is too long, please do some debugging and reduce the code down to become a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying the line-through to the `li` element, you should apply it to the actual text element, in your case it's the `h2` tag.

Change your CSS to

```css
.checked h2 {
    text-decoration: line-through red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the line-through text decoration on the `checked` class to draw the red line, you can do it via a pseudo class. This will set the line above the element.

To make this work, give `#itemList li` a `position: relative`, and create the pseudo class on `.checked` like this:

```
.checked::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This draws a red line across the entire width of the element, at 1px height, with some vertical centering via `top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;`.